# Spring integration properties for Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

While trying to use listener config properties in application.yml, I am facing an issue where the KafkaListener annotated method is not invoked at all if I use the application.yml config(listener.type= batch). It only gets invoked when I explicitly set setBatchListener to true in code. Here is my code and configuration.

1. Consumer code:

```
@KafkaListener(containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
        topics = "${spring.kafka.template.default-topic}",
        groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    public void receive(List<ConsumerRecord<String,byte[]>> consumerRecords,Acknowledgment acknowledgment){
        processor.process(consumerRecords,acknowledgment);
    }
```

2. application.yml:

```
    listener:
      missing-topics-fatal: false
      type: batch
      ack-mode: manual
```

3. Consumer configuration:

   ```
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(
            new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties()));
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler( new UpdateMessageErrorHandler(),new FixedBackOff(idleEventInterval,maxFailures)));
    final ContainerProperties properties = factory.getContainerProperties();
    properties.setIdleBetweenPolls(idleBetweenPolls);
    properties.setIdleEventInterval(idleEventInterval);
    return factory;
   ```

   }

Comment: Please, choose tags for your questions carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-integration/info. See respective help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, by using the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` builder in your configuration you're essentially overriding a piece of code that is usually executed within `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` class within spring autoconfiguration package:

```java
        if (properties.getType().equals(Type.BATCH)) {
            factory.setBatchListener(true);
            factory.setBatchErrorHandler(this.batchErrorHandler);
        } else {
            factory.setErrorHandler(this.errorHandler);
        }
```

Since it's hardcoded in your `application.yaml` file anyway, why is it a bad thing for it to be configured in your `@Configuration` file?

Comment: This is correct; you should use Boot's auto configured factory and then set any additional properties on it (for properties that are not directly supported by Boot).

Comment: Thanks @Desomph, it helped me resolve the problem. However, I still needed to invoke the configure method of ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.